# Pinning objects to other objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I am creating an app using XIBs. However, the objects don't line up the same way on the 4" screen as they do on the 3.5" screen. I think that one way to solve this, would be to lock my objects to my background image (so that it is always the same distance from the bottom of the image). Is it possible to do this?

Ask for more information if this question is too vague.

Comment: Have you looked into AutoLayout?

Comment: You should use auto layout, and give your objects vertical constraints to each other, with the bottom  most object having a constraint to the bottom of the main view. If you don't know how to use auto layout, you should watch the videos (there are 3 of them) from the WWDC 2012 meeting.

Comment: The thing is, my background image is the size of the 4" screen, so when viewed on a 3.5" screen, only the middle section is shown and the top and bottom parts are cut off. Therefore, the constraint from the background image to the bottom of the main view changes between the 3.5 and 4" screens.

Comment: How are you setting this background image?

Comment: I am just using a Image View to display an image, and putting it behind the rest of the views on the screen.

Comment: If the image view is the size of the screen, and you set the image in IB (or with setImage:), then that image should shrink or expand with the image view with different screen sizes (assuming that the image view has constraints to all 4 sides of the main view).

Comment: I don't want the image to shrink or expand, I just have it so that the 4" screen reveals a little more than the 3.5". All I want to be able to do, is pin my objects so that they always stay the same distance from the bottom of that image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42752/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user2397282)